# Android: Creating timeslot using tableview

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create an application where users can select a date and a timeslot on that day. I am trying to design it in tableview, but I am not exactly how to go about creating it.

What I want is for users to be able to scroll through the dates with arrows left and right, and then select a timeslot on that particular day with timeslots available each half an hour, i.e. 10.00-10:30 10:30-11:00 with the 2 time slots per column. I know I have to program this using Java, but I not exactly sure how I would go about doing this.

Would be very grateful if someone could give some assistance or point me towards some tutorials that might help me learn how to create something like this

Thanks in advance

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old question, forgot to say, figured it out using GridView. Back when I asked this, I did not know enough about Android development

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a fairly general question, so the best I can do is give you a general answer. First, have you had chance to look at the [Date Picker](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html) class? This is definitely going to be one component of the solution to your problem. Second, I think the best thing for you to do would be to have a date picker for selecting the date, and then a ListView for selecting the time slot. The ListView would just have a bunch predefined time slots that you put in it. Or maybe they'd be dynamic. I don't know. Your choice.

Comment: I am aware of the datepicker class and have used it in other applications, however I would like the timeslots to be available in half an hour slots so I can grey out the timeslots that are not available.

The idea being that it will look like this

         <   November 16 2011  >

        10:00 - 10:30   10:30 - 11:00
        11:00 - 11:30   11:30 - 12:00

I probably shoulda explained it better in original post. It's this idea that I would like to implement, and just trying to find good tutorials that explain how I would go about doing this